# Android app: google map is blank

Tags: android, api, google-maps, maps

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm) in order to get a map to show on my app.
For some reason, when the app opens, I get the map controls and the Google logo but the screen is grey. 
Logcat says:

```
11-12 20:06:36.219    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@65d4c588 not retrying
11-12 20:06:36.219    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.j@659c6178
11-12 20:06:36.219    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@65b4cf80
11-12 20:06:42.329    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
11-12 20:06:42.329    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
11-12 20:06:42.909    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(49): 62|15|147
11-12 20:06:42.909    8568-8644/com.example.examapp D/REQUEST﹕ Close
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled **Google Maps Android API v2** in the APIs list on your project's [Google page](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and you are using the **same Keystore to sign you application from which you have generated the map keys**.
The keyStore you used here in this command

> keytool -list -v -alias **androiddebugkey** -keystore **%%Your path%%**
>   -storepass android -keypass android

[image]

Comment: Yup you have have your own key but are signing your application with the same keystore file by which you have created the map keys

Comment: Yes, i basically created the api key for this purpose. the keystore i pasted in the google console is the form : 3E:2B:D2:39:B2:FE:5E:E6:45:24:C5:4C:0B:32:6C:D2:97:79:65:B4;com.example

Comment: the keystore placed at this path %%your path%% have you used the same when creating your application for signing purpose or your eclipse is using the same key store.

Comment: the steps i took: opened the command line, did the keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android , took the sha-1 certificate fingerprint, went to google console on create new api key, pasted the fingerprint and added semicolon and the name of the package which is com.example. then took the api key and pasted it into the manifest file. Not sure if it is any usefull, but i am using Android studio for Mac

Comment: try signing your application go to this link http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html there go to heading Signing Your App in Android Studio  then follow steps 1 and then go to step 4 there give the path of keystore present at  .android/debug.keystore and fill the other details as use used in the above command you mentioned then try running the apk created by this process and tell if maps are visible then or not.

Comment: @Ionut Paraschiv  after trying do tell us.

Comment: when i try to do that, using the existing keystore, the build of apk fails and i get the following error : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key from keystore..  im ,most likely, doing something wrong

Comment: do you have eclipse ? it will be easy from that since i cannot see or tell you the steps, what are you doing as i use eclipse  i can guide you if you use eclipse step by step.

Comment: I have to stop working on it for now. but ill get back at it in the afternoon, and try doing it with eclipse. Thanks a lot for your time